# Using Page Builder Apply the Multiple Template

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, page-builder

I am using a page builder in Magento2. I need to apply the multiple templates in blocks or on the page but once I apply the one admin template on a block it's overwritten the older template. Please suggest to me how I can add the multiple admin template on the block and page.